# Add users to Active Directory and roles programmatically to tfs project

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2012, tfs, active-directory, tfs-sdk

How can I add users to Active Directory and roles programmatically to a fresh created tfs project?

I'm working with VS2012, TFS 2010, SQL Server 2012.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you theses links :

Get user from AD : http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/599697/Get-list-of-Active-Directory-users-in-Csharp

Add user to TFS : http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/599697/Get-list-of-Active-Directory-users-in-Csharp